# Как указать главный класс при сборки jar GRADLE

Tags: java, gradle

Мне нужно указать в build.gradle чтобы он считал главный класс - с методом main был допустим hello.java

Comment: ничего не понял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apply plugin: 'java'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.example.Hello'
    }
}
```